# android studio. combine two projects

Tags: android, android-activity, layout, module, project

android studio
I am doing a large project and therefore I create many small projects to develop new functionality.
for example: made a project in which there is a map and markers.
and the second project in which I made a navigation block. How can these two projects be merged now?

you need to add activity_maps.xml here. can I do this? or everything should be done in one project.
it is necessary for this activity to work as it should, but displayed there.
the task is this: from the first module you need to refer to the xml [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rqpv.png)file of the second module.

Comment: You don't need to create 2 project for it. Just creating new Java Class. "File > New > Java Class"

Answer (score 0):

Well you can share resources by adding small projects as modules. There is no rule for creating single project or using modularization, it totally depends on the requirement of the project. And modularization has lots of benefits like reusability, isolation, build speed, scalability and many more.
If you want to use maps4 resources in app add below code in app

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':maps4')
   }
```

You can [read](https://jeroenmols.com/blog/2019/03/06/modularizationwhy/) this blog for app modularization tips

**Edited**

First thing here change compile to implementation as compile is deprecated. So in your app's build.gradle file change compile project(':maps4') to implementation project(':maps4').

And if you have successfully added maps4 as module in your main project below code should work

```
tools:layout = "@layout/activity_maps"
```

If this line still shows error, make sure you have made required changes in maps4 build.gradle to be used as module

change

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
```

to

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
```

remove this line

```
applicationId "<your app id>"
```

After making these two changes hit sync now on top of build.gradle file.

Comment: and then in the hml file where I selected the line write:
tools:layout = "maps4/res/layout/activity_maps"
??

Comment: I have edited my answer with your query as well.

Comment: two applications are created on the smartphone and by pressing the button the map is not shown, the old fragment is shown

Comment: I find it better to add the map component itself to my slide-out project. so should weigh less